# Running python-file on SQL server 2017

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server-2017

I have enabled running Python queries on my SQL-server and I am able to run simple queries like these ones:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/run-python-using-t-sql?view=sql-server-2017

However I have a python-file with a main-function calling several other pyshon packages in seperate files. I would like to run this main-file from sql server. I think I have some errors in the file, but would like to have these printed when running the code.

When I tried the following statement my import statements didn't work:

```
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
exec(open(FILEPATH).read())
'
```

When I tried the following it executes but terminates too fast because of some error. However it does not print the error messages from the code.

```
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen( FILEPATH, shell=True)
'
```

When I tried the following it doesn't seem t execute, just finish running after 0 seconds, and does not print any error messages:

```
execute sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
os.system(FILEPATH)
'
```

Can anyone help me with how to run my python packages from sql server in a way where I can see the error messages?

Comment: Can't you just do `import filename`? The file/package has to be on the SQL Server box though.